# How can I change one character in a file without writing the whole file again?

Tags: linux, file-io, file, filesystems

How do I change one character in a file? Any nix-compliant programming language solution is welcome.

I wrote .pgm file and put the magic number to 'P2'. The correct one is 'P5'. Now I have 100000+ files to fix. Alternatively: how do I read my new file with pylab.imread()?

FYI: pgm is an ascii image file format http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html. pylab and PIL require magic number to be P5

br,
Juha

**edit:** Thank you for all solutions. dd-method is the only that works. For curiosity, why the c and python do not?

Comment: Not sure why the Python version is not working.. I just tried with this:
with open('testmap.txt', 'r+b') as f:
   map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
   map[:2] = 'P5'
   map.close()
   f.close()
And it seems to work fine. You could try setting the 'length' parameter of mmap() function to something like 2, to avoid it mapping the whole file.

Comment: Argh - the code looks awful in the comments.. I pasted it here: http://pastebin.com/sjkBTQiG

Comment: Python solution works now. reason: wb -> rb+ (see comments below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talking about solutions not involving Python, one would be something like:

```
echo -n "P5" | dd of=yourfile.pgm conv=notrunc
```

That will cause dd to write "P5" at the beginning of the file, without truncating it

Answer (score 1):

In python you could memory map the file using the [mmap](http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html) module.

```
f = open("yourfile.pgm", "rb+")
map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
map[1] = "5"
map.close()
```

Comment: > python test_18/fixMagicNumber.py
<open file 'test_18/test_18_00000002.fpf.pgm', mode 'wb' at 0x2b5116032eb8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_18/fixMagicNumber.py", line 8, in ?
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 2)
ValueError: mmap length is greater than file size

Comment: I get the above error when trying this with: 
from glob import glob
import mmap

for fn in glob('*/*00002.fpf.pgm'):
    f = open(fn,'wb')
    print f
    m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 2)
    m[1] = '5'
    m.close()
    f.close()

Comment: it's more fun! :)  Seriously, you are probably right - for a small file like this seek and write are easier.

Comment: filesize seems to be zero afterwards

Comment: Juha: I don't know what the problem is, which OS are you using?

Comment: linux centos (redhat) 64bit, 2.6.18-194.17.4.el5, x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Weird, the example I gave works for me on Ubuntu 10.10 i686, with Python 2.6.6.

Comment: I like the mmap idea, but as others have written, seek and write are just as good in this situation.

Comment: @andrewmu: "seek and write are just as good in this situation".  Not quite.  They're simpler and more clear.  You might want to make that change, too.

Comment: I actually prefer memory map for binary files because it's potentially much more efficient for access and buffering, etc.  If this was a large image file or e.g., a chunk of a JPEG, I'd rather treat the thing as an array, e.g. extracting offsets, jumping forward, writing bytes, than as a unix file where I'd be seeking, writing, having to think about the file pointer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In C:

```
FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r+b");
fputs("P5", f);
fclose(f);
```

It'll be the same procedure (open-as-binary/write/close) in just about any language.

Most importantly: **First, backup everything.**

**EDIT:** I removed the fseek because the magic string is at the beginning of the file, which is where `fopen(..., "r+b")` positions the file pointer.

Comment: This also fails, below is the valgrind output:==18618== Invalid read of size 2
==18618==    at 0x3F8E462184: fwrite (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==18618==    by 0x4005D3: main (fixMagic.c:11)
==18618==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: For the sake of brevity, I didn't do any error-checking. You should have. The call to `fopen()` probably failed and returned the null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know where it is you can read the first x bytes then edit the bytes, then write back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to save the files after you modify them of course, but I don't see why you'd think you have to rewrite every single byte.